# ¿Como eliminar un archivo?

Tags: php, mysql, archivo

¡Hola!,resulta que necesito eliminar un archivo, produje la el metodo unlink()antes me borraba pero ahora no se me borra, envio los parametros via GET , y me los toma , me elimina el registro pero no me elimina el archivo en el directorio , adjunto imagen :

[image: Codigo para eliminar el registro y el archivo que se subio]

```html
    <td><a class="btn btn-danger btn-raised btn-xs" onclick='return confirmDelete()' href="eliminar.php?iddaem=<?php echo $fila["iddaem"] ?>&&ruta=<?php echo $fila["ruta"] ?>">
                                            <i class="zmdi zmdi-delete"></i></a></td>
```

Este es el codigo que envio los parametros hacia la vista eliminar.php mediante GET , cabe recalcar que la ruta lo tengo guardado en una base de datos y hay hago la consulta , de tipo varchar ,antes me funcionaba como decia pero ahora no , de antemano Muchas Gracias!

(Editado)

Aqui esta el directorio y estos son los parametros que me llegan :

[image: Directorio]

Lo que llega al enviar los parametros GET a la vista eliminar ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Basicamente asi está bien el código, necesitamos saber donde guardas los documentos y que te llega en la variable ruta, otra cosa , que pasa si por get te llega la variable $id asi $id='1;DROP TABLE daem'

Comment: @CristianCamilo Gracias por responder Cristan! , lo guardo en una carpeta o directorio , y el parametro que me llega tanto en id como la ruta es : $id = 255(dependiendo del id seleccionado ,llega un numero),$ruta=../../subidas/archivo eso seria basicamente

Comment: intenta hacer esto con la ruta     file_get_contents($ruta)  probablemente tu ruta esta mal si no te trae nada,o tambien puedes usar file_exists($ruta), para saber si realmente existe, en caso tal deberia funcionar tu eliminación ismepre y cuando tengas permisos

Comment: Agrega el código como texto en lugar de usar screenshots.